# Custom Block Config - Accepting array of objects

Tags: blocks, configuration

I have built a component following [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-blocks/add-a-form-to-the-block-configuration) but am wanting to add configure to allow the user to add a series of objects that each contain a 'title' (a text field) and a 'content' (a list of text fields) and cannot seem to find this documented anywhere. Ideally the user could select the block and then, in the configuration, add as many afore-mentioned objects to have them all be displayed wherever the block is placed.

Right now the 'hello world' demo in the docs looks like:

`$form['hello_block_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Who'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Who do you want to say hello to?'),
      '#default_value' => isset($config['hello_block_name']) ? $config['hello_block_name'] : '',
    ];`

Any clarification or tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use webforms: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Comment: Not sure that I follow. I was hoping to enable a user to be able to add configuration to a custom block on the admin page, this seems to work on pages. Are you saying I could throw this into the custom block config UI?